# asn1tools to encoded the asn.1 failed

Tags: asn.1

The asn.1 file(test.asn) is as follows, I want to use python to encode the file to get the bitstring of the asn.1, but when I use python to encode it as per not ber, the error occured. I didn't know what's the meaning of the exception. Please help to check it.

```
RRC DEFINITIONS ::=BEGIN
RRCConnectionRequest-NB ::=     SEQUENCE {

    criticalExtensions                  CHOICE {

        rrcConnectionRequest-r13            RRCConnectionRequest-NB-r13-IEs,

        criticalExtensionsFuture            SEQUENCE {}

    }

}



RRCConnectionRequest-NB-r13-IEs ::=     SEQUENCE {

    ue-Identity-r13                         InitialUE-Identity,

    establishmentCause-r13                  EstablishmentCause-NB-r13,

    multiToneSupport-r13                    ENUMERATED {true}               OPTIONAL,

    multiCarrierSupport-r13                 ENUMERATED {true}               OPTIONAL,

    spare                                   BIT STRING (SIZE (22))

}
EstablishmentCause-NB-r13 ::=           ENUMERATED {

                                        mt-Access, mo-Signalling, mo-Data, mo-ExceptionData,

                                        delayTolerantAccess-v1330, spare3, spare2, spare1}

InitialUE-Identity ::=              CHOICE {

    randomValue                         BIT STRING (SIZE (40))

}



END
```

The python code is as follows:

```
def asn_try():
    rrc = asn1tools.compile_files('/home/zhf/py_prj/test.asn','per')

    encoded = rrc.encode('RRCConnectionRequest-NB',
                         {'criticalExtensions': ('rrcConnectionRequest-r13', {
                             'ue-Identity-r13': ('randomValue', (b'01', 2)), 'establishmentCause-r13': 'mt-Access',
                             'multiToneSupport-r13': 'true', 'multiCarrierSupport-r13': 'true', 'spare': (b'01', 2)})})
    print(encoded.hex())
    print(encoded)
    print(rrc.decode('RRCConnectionRequest-NB', encoded))
```

But the error orrured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhf/py_prj/function_test/asn_try.py", line 36, in <module>
    asn_try()
  File "/home/zhf/py_prj/function_test/asn_try.py", line 15, in asn_try
    print(rrc.decode('RRCConnectionRequest-NB', encoded))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/compiler.py", line 116, in decode
    return self._types[name].decode(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 1541, in decode
    return self._type.decode(decoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 764, in decode
    return self.decode_root(decoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 776, in decode_root
    value = member.decode(decoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 1354, in decode
    return self.decode_root(decoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 1365, in decode_root
    return (member.name, member.decode(decoder))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 764, in decode
    return self.decode_root(decoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 776, in decode_root
    value = member.decode(decoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 1354, in decode
    return self.decode_root(decoder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 1365, in decode_root
    return (member.name, member.decode(decoder))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 991, in decode
    value = decoder.read_bits(number_of_bits)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/codecs/per.py", line 317, in read_bits
    raise OutOfDataError(self.number_of_read_bits())
asn1tools.codecs.per.OutOfDataError: criticalExtensions: ue-Identity-r13: out of data at bit offset 8 (1.0 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

asn1tools does not take all constraints into account when encoding a BIT STRING. asn1tools will encode the number of bits given by the user, and if that differs from the number of bits in the ASN.1 specification the encoding still succeeds. However, when decoding the constraint is taken into account, and in your case an OutOfDataError exception is raised since the encoded 2 bits are less than 40 (see `BIT STRING (SIZE (40))`) needed when decoding. If you use the data below both encoding and decoding works.

```
{
    'criticalExtensions': (
        'rrcConnectionRequest-r13',
        {
            'ue-Identity-r13': (
                'randomValue', (b'\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01', 40)
            ),
            'establishmentCause-r13': 'mt-Access',
            'multiToneSupport-r13': 'true',
            'multiCarrierSupport-r13': 'true',
            'spare': (b'\x01\x01\x00', 22)
        }
    )
}
```

Also, the `per` codec is the aligned variant of the Packed Encoding Rules. The 3GPP RRC specification uses Unaligned Packed Encoding Rules, which is `uper` in asn1tools.

/ Erik